# I want to fetch multiple data from oracle database and want to store it into another variables in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net

I want to fetch multiple data from oracle database and want to store it into another variables in C# .net.

I am using this code.

```
public static void FetchData(string MeterSerialNumber, string MeterManufacturer, string MeterType, XmlDocument xmlReXML, string StartTime, string StopTime)

    {
        string Acctid = "";
        string Ser = "";
        string name1 = "";
        string towns = "";
        string Qry = "SELECT DISTINCT AC.ACCOUNTID as accid ,MT.SERIALNUMBER as srno,AC.NAME as names,OC.OPCONAME as town1,OC.CITY discm FROM ACCOUNT AC, XXMETERHIST M, LSMDPHYSICALMETER MT,LSSERVICEPOINT P,LSMDMTRMANUFACTURER MANUFAC,OPERATINGCOMPANY OC,LSMARKET LS WHERE AC.UIDACCOUNT = M.UIDACCOUNT AND M.UIDPHYSICALMETER = MT.UIDPHYSICALMETER and LS.MARKETID = OC.OPCOCODE and LS.UIDMARKET = P.UIDMARKET and MANUFAC.UIDMTRMANUFACTURER = MT.UIDMETERMANUFACTURER AND M.UIDSERVICEPOINT = P.UIDSERVICEPOINT and MT.SERIALNUMBER ='?' AND MT.UIDPHYSMTRTYPE = '43'";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("provider=MSDAORA.oracle;user id=testapp;password=testapp;data source=mdmdb_tb");
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter dad = new OleDbDataAdapter(Qry, con);
        dad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = MeterSerialNumber;
        con.Open();

        dtbl.Columns.Add("accid");
        dtbl.Columns.Add("srno");
        dtbl.Columns.Add("names");
        dtbl.Columns.Add("town1");
        dtbl.Columns.Add("discm");
        dad.Fill(dtbl);
       if (dtbl.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
            Acctid = (dtbl.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
            Ser = (dtbl.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString());
            name1 = (dtbl.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString());
            towns = (dtbl.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString());

      }
    }
```

But the data is not saved in all the variables.Its throwing Indexout of boundrange exception.

Comment: When you run this through the debugger, which line is the exception on?

Comment: Suspect the problem is with ItemArray.  You don't show the declaration.

Comment: @Blam, `ItemArray` won't have a declaration.  It's a property on `DataRow`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that this would be the root of the issue, but this might be giving you some weird data from your SQL query:

Did you mean `OC.CITY AS discm` instead of `OC.CITY discm`?

Also, just a suggestions that you might want to specify a type for the columns of your datatable:

```
dtbl.Columns.Add("accid", typeof(int));
dtbl.Columns.Add("srno", typeof(int));
dtbl.Columns.Add("names", typeof(string));
```

etc.